# Should we use plasterboard, MDF or wood when blocking up a window in our pantry?

Tags: drywall, windows, mdf

We have a window in our pantry and we have been advised that we might need planning permission to remove it. Instead it would be easier to put plaster board over it.

I was just curious whether plaster board, MDF or wood might be better because we intend to put shelves up on this wall.

Answer (score 1):

In most localities it is illegal to permanently block a window from the inside only. The reason being in an emergency fire fighters may waste time trying to enter a blocked window. The amount of difficulty to do it properly will vary based mostly on the type of exterior siding. I would remove the window, frame it in with 2x4's or what ever the wall is framed with. Install any blocking that will help with mounting the shelves. Install sheathing to allow the siding to fit flush with the exterior. Install plasterboard to fit flush with the existing interior wall including any insulation.

Comment: So would I need to block it from the outside as well? If it helps I live in the uk. Can I provide any information to help decide what I can do?

Comment: The most accurate information on what you can and cannot do will come from your local council or who ever has jurisdiction over these things. You may find you can remove the window entirely with no problems. It rarely hurts to simply ask.